# Can't get input line editing to work in JLine3

Tags: jline3

I'm struggling with the basics of getting a simple console application to work with JLine3.

I've initialized it like this:

```
    terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder()
                .streams(System.in, System.out)
                .build();
    lineReader = LineReaderBuilder.builder().terminal(terminal).build();
```

and I try to read a line like this:

```
    String in = lineReader.readLine("/>").trim();
```

and if the user just types text correctly, I get the right input. Backspace works for correcting the input. But moving the cursor back using the left arrow key doesn't; instead of the cursor moving, I see `^[0D` displayed on the screen.

I tried various other options but nothing changed. I want to move on in due course to exploit history and auto-completion, but I'm failing at the first baby steps.

I've obviously missed something basic (but the documentation isn't good...)

Using JLine 3.13.3 on MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: In the absence of an answer, I switched to JLine2 which is better documented, and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a terminal for the real console the JVM is running in, you'd rather use:

```
     terminal = TerminalBuilder
                .builder()
                .system(true)
                .build();
```

That should work better...

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I've shipped with JLine2 for the moment, but I'll give this a try when I get a chance.